# Why wont the softkeyboard show here?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-dialogfragment

I'm in a `DialogFragment` in the `onCreateDialog` I'm using the `InputMethodManager` to show the keyboard when the dialog opens. But, its not working for some reason. Anyone know why?

```
        @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder b = new Builder(getActivity());

        b.setMessage("Enter a 5 digit zipcode");
        final EditText et = new EditText(getActivity());
        et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        et.requestFocus();
        et.setHint("Zipcode");
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(et, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
        b.setView(et);          
        return b.create();
    }
```

Comment: I just came across same problem just a sec.

Comment: Well the code you posted, and I posted works.  I am guessing that in your case it just never gets created because you are in the dialog  by the time its created.

Comment: So its a matter of the dialog for sure.  Only other possibility is that the code does not get called which is unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your code on an Android device? If you are using an android emulator, chances are that your Keyboard Support inside the Hardware properties for your emulator is turned off.

To enable it, go to AVD Manager-> Edit AVD-> Hardware-> Add Keyboard Support / Edit Keyboard Support and enable its value

Comment: I'm running on a 4.1 Galaxy Nexus.

Answer (score 0):

You need perhaps to request focus on EditText.  Also I found getWindow() more reliable if avail on Dialog.

```
       InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    et.requestFocus();
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

Update my answer.  Your dialog is perhaps already running.  So the request is made at the current window then you create the dialog.  The dialog has its own window perhaps and so it does not show?

Comment: I was already requesting focus, I tried getActivity.getWindow()... it also doesn't work.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution to force open the keyboard in onCreateDialog() ? I read a lot of answer but nothing works.